# RxJava - How to stop a running task when new item emitted

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java

I am building searching feature for my Android app with RxJava. When users type/change query characters in an `EditText`, an emitter will emit new query text and I search around my database to get results that match the query.

```
getEditTextObservable()
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
                .debounce(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .filter {
                    !it.isNullOrEmpty()
                }
                .map {
                    //start searching
                    getResultsInDatabase(it) //this function takes a long time to complete
                }.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe{
                    //render results on screen
                }
```

The method `getResultsInDatabase(string:String)` take a long time to complete, when the query text changed, I want to stop method `getResultsInDatabase(string:String)` (in case it is running with previously emitted query) to run it again with new query. How can I do to achieve that? I would appreciate your helps. Thank you for reading my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a `switchMap`.

```
getEditTextObservable()
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
    .debounce(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
    .filter { !it.isNullOrEmpty() } //Be careful with this. Should clearing text clear results too?
    .switchMap { 
        Observable.fromCallable { getResultsInDatabase(it) }.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()) 
    }.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe{
        //render results on screen
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try and send you feedback.

Comment: I changed `map` to `switchMap` as you suggested but it doesnt work as I expected.

Comment: This is more or less how I write my own search functions with Rx, so that's surprising. `switchMap` works by creating a new subscription whenever upstream changes. This means that when a new emission comes through about the query changing, it drops the earlier subscription to get your database results, and starts a new chain. Perhaps you should add a scheduler that uses a thread pool (io()), to fetch your results, and add it to the `fromCallable{ }`.

Comment: Thank you, I follow your comment and now it works well. Just modify your answer and I will accept it. Btw, could you explain in more detail?

Comment: About adding the io scheduler? My theory here was that if your database is queried on a single thread, then you can't effectively drop a subscription and start a new one, because those queries are still synchronous. You'd need to wait for an earlier query to complete before you can start a new one, regardless of whether you request it to stop or not. By using a thread pool, you can just start a new query on another thread in that pool, and use that. I've updated my answer so let me know whether that's what you need.

Comment: I have played with `switchMap` operator. I realized that `subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())` is just a statement to prevent the code in `fromCallable` block from being executed before a new item emitted. Your answer still works well even when I use `subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())` and remove `subscribeOn`, `debounce` operators.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `valve` to pause a stream in **RxJava**. Based on the value of it, the stream continues to emit or will be kept in a paused state.

Comment: Thank you. I am new to RxJava, I will search for `valve` and try to apply it.